# Как перегрузить оператор "," что бы он давал значение площади прямоугольника?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Есть объект класса , у меня есть длина и ширина прямоугольника. Как правильно написать перегрузку операции, что бы функция не принимала никаких аргументов. Но вовзращала значение площади. например, есть объект R. К ней я применяю оператор %R и у меня на выходе получается площадь

Comment: Непонятно, о каком именно операторе вы говорите? в заголовке запятая, в тексте %...

Answer (score 3):

Вы не имеете права превращать бинарный оператор в унарный. Поэтому выбирать можете только из унарных операторов (но не забывайте при этом, что ассоциативность и приоритет оператора остается тем же, что и у неперегруженного!).

Так что в вашем варианте, например:

```
class Rectangle {
...
int width, height;
...
int operator ~() const { return width*height; }
```

Так что можете писать `S = ~R;`  :)

Но - еще и еще раз:

1. Ассоциативность и приоритет использованного оператора не изменяется.
2. Изменение семантики оператора всегда дурно пахнет. Использование оператора `~` для вычисления площади, как сделал я - пример нехороший, потому что в оригинале семантика такого оператора - побитовое отрицание...

Comment: понял вас спасибо" , " является бинарным оператором?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/comma-operator?view=msvc-160, например. А как вы его представляете как унарный?... `x=,y`? :)

Comment: спасибо. Понял. Но теперь другая проблема bool operator>(Rectangle& R, Rectangle& M) const;. Пытаюсь перегрузить оператор ">", но компилятор выдает ошибку, что слишком много параметров для этой функции оператора.

Comment: Это покажите в отдельном вопросе. Оператор член класса или нет и т.д.

Comment: А вы его перегружаете как член класса или как свободный оператор? Не забывайте, что у члена класса один аргумент есть всегда - сам объект класса, `*this`.