# Почему компилятор выдает ошибку на указатель this

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Существует класс, который описывает взаимодействие с прямоугольником. В приватных данных его 2 точки.

```
class Rectangle
{
private:
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
public:
    Rectangle() { x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0; }
    Rectangle(int x1_, int y1_, int x2_, int y2);
    ~Rectangle() {}
    int operator~() const;
    bool operator>(const Rectangle &M);
    //friend bool operator>(const Rectangle &M, const Rectangle&R);
    bool operator*(const Rectangle& M) const;
    void operator<<(const Rectangle& M) const;
};
```

Сначала перегружаю операцию "~", которая находит площадь прямоугольника. Вот ее код:

```
int Rectangle:: operator~() const
{
    int length = x2 - x1;
    int width =y1 - y2;
    return length * width;
}
```

Затем хочу перегрузить операцию ">" которая сравнивает две площади прямоугольника и выдает 1, если площадь первого больше площади второго.

```
bool Rectangle:: operator>(const Rectangle &M)
{
 if ((~this)>(~M))
  return 1;
else
   return 0;
}
```

Компилятор ругается на ~this. Вопрос, почему это происходит? И как изменить без применения дружественной функции.

Comment: `this` - это указатель. Попробуйте так: `~(*this)`

Comment: Почему вдруг оператор ~ возвращает плщадь?

Comment: во первых, это красиво:). во вторых - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213390/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0

Comment: @user7860670 перегрузка оператора.

Comment: можете сразу возвращать результат сравнения:      `return operator~() > ~M;` Или как подсказал EOF

Comment: Думаю тут  `operator *` логичней    чем   `operator~`,

Comment: @KoVadim ... во-третьих, удобно, в-четвертых, непонятно и наукообразно

Answer (score 1):

Вызывать унарный оператор нужно для объекта, а `this` - указатель на объект. Для получения ссылки его нужно разыменовать:

```
~(*this)
```

Но можно вспомнить, что оператор - это просто функция, и вызывать для указателя на объект так:

```
this->operator~()
```

Comment: Да, можно и так:)

Answer (score 0):

`this` - это указатель, который указывает на объект, который вызывал метод. Чтобы получить объект из указателя необходимо его разыменовать. Вот так: `*this`. Т.е. Ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
bool Rectangle::operator>(const Rectangle &M)
{
    if ((~*this) > (~M))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Также стоит заметить, что такая перегрузка операторов не будет очевидной для людей, которые потом будут читать код. Может лучше написать метод `getArea()`,  который будет возвращать площадь. Тогда оператор сравнения можно будет написать так:

```
bool Rectangle::operator>(const Reactangle& r)
{
    return getArea() > r.getArea();
}
```

Comment: Действительны вы правы, задание было перегрузить операции, которые выдают площадь, и перегрузить еще 1 оператор, который выдает больше ли прямоугольник по площади или нет

Comment: А еще его можно вызывать так: `this->operator~()`.